# Why does omitting this "li" CSS selector affect the applied style?

Tags: css

The code goes like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
#nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#nav li {float:left; display:inline; cursor:pointer; list-style:none; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:1px #000 solid; 
position:relative;}


li, li a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
#nav .nav li { width:100%; text-indent:10px; line-height:30px; margin-right:10px; border-top:1px #000 solid; 
border-bottom:1px #000 solid; border-left:none; border-right:none; background:#fff;}
#nav li a {display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit;}

ul.nav { display:none; }
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid; }
li:hover { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="nav first">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>


</body>
```

On the third element at the `"li, li a"` part, If I remove the `"li"` selector leaving only the `"li a"`, what happens is, when I hover at my first level list items, the second list items appear, but the text doesn't, I don't know if it's a background influence, or a text influence, because I can't find what influences my 2nd level lists!

Oh and by the way, the first menu called "Menu 1" under the first level list item, is visible, I think its because of the "li a" selector, but as for the part where that I deleted, I don't know how it works, can someone tell me what's causing this trouble when I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `a` tag only to the first sub item of "Menu 1". and you are giving text color as white(#FFF) by the following code:

```
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
```

Thats why the text is not being visible because the background is also white. but when you hovering on the `li`'s, the text is being visible because you are changing the background color to black by doing the following.

```
li,li a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;} //assigning text color of li as black
```

If you remove `li` from the above code then the text color inside the li elements will remain white color as you mentioned in the very above code.

Comment: I could have gave more explanation but I am bit kind of busy here. I hope you got what I meant here.

Comment: Technically, the text *is* visible.  It just happens to be the same color as the background.  If it had `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`, then you wouldn't be able to highlight the text at all.

Comment: @cimmanon That's exactly what I meant in my post. Let me edit my post for better understanding.

Comment: I now have a clue how to understand it, but I'm still in pieces. 
Sorry, I'm still a newbie in CSS. T_T

Answer (score 0):

The line `li, li a` means that the styles are being applied to all LI's and all A's contained inside LI's.

All your styling is being applied relatively.  Meaning anything applied to `li, li a` is going to affect every LI and ever A nested inside an LI that is present.  Regardless of whether it is a parent, or a child menu.

Since `.nav` is a class applied to the sub-menu, you can target the li's there by including `.nav` in your  selector.  For example: `#nav .nav li a`

To hide your submenu you need simply:

```
#nav li ul.nav { display: none; }
```

Then to make it appear on hover (presuming this is what you want)

```
#nav li:hover ul.nav { display: block; }
```

Have I answered all questions?

Comment: That was a good explanation, but not entirely my question, but thanks for contributing.